# Getting the creator and the last modifier of a Lotus Domino document

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I'd like to get the creator and the last modifier of Lotus Domino document. How could I do this?

I've found the [`Authors` property](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTESNOTECOLLECTION_CLASS.html), which is a `Vector` but its ordering isn't defined in the documentation. Can I rely on that that the first element is the creator and the last one is the last modifier?

Comment: Do you want to check only existing documents or change the design to track creator/modificator?

Comment: @pstr: Just checking existing document. I can' modify the database (I have only read-only access).

Comment: Are you sure there's no field value that's already set to the document creator? I would think that if it matters who created it, the designer would put that in a field.

Comment: @DavidNavarre: I'm collecting metadata and statistical information from multiple databases. They probably have that information in custom items but currently it's out of scope to discover internal database structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `$UpdatedBy` field directly. (I think `Authors` property also uses it.) In this field all updaters are stored in chronological order: originator -- first, last modified -- last.

It can show you wrong data if the option *"Limit entries in `$UpdatedBy` fields"* is set in database properties: when it reaches the limit it deletes first entry in `$UpdatedBy`, so you couldn't be known about document creator.

Comment: i found that using index 1 gives the first in the field: `$updatedby[1]`

Answer (score 5):

The safest solution is to set up a 'computed when composed' type field on the design that's set to the current user when the doc is created, and another one that'd hold the last modifier name (something like `@SetField("LastUpdatedby";@UserName)` in the `QuerySave` event).

In your case, if you just want to gather data from an existing application and there is no manually added field you could use, there will be a few facts to take into consideration:

1.) the `$UpdatedBy` item and the Authors property are the same: using the Authors property from Lotusscript will return an array gathered from the `$Updatedby` item.

2.) the `$UpdatedBy` item can not be manipulated = from this aspect it would be safe to use it

3.) Assuming that you've got the whole history there*, you'll get the creator with a formula like `@Subset($Updatedby;1)` or `Cstr(updatedbyarray(Lbound(updatedbyarray)))` in lotusscript

4.) You'll always get the last modifier by looking at the last entry in the `$Updatedby` array using `@Subset($Updatedby;-1)` or `Cstr(array(Ubound(array)))`.

5*.) There is a possibility that your DB has a limitation in place for the `$Updatedby` entries, as these can be quite space consuming (DB level settings, last tab, Limit entries in `$UpdatedBy` fields). Once you hit this limit Notes will start deleting the old entries when there is a new one to be added, and querying the first member of the array won't give you the creator anymore.

6.) Due to the possibility that you won't find the creator in the `$Updatedby` array, you should protect your code with something like this:

```
If Ubound(var)+1 <> db.LimitUpdatedBy Then 
    'You are safe
Else 
    Msgbox "Ouch!"
End If
```

If it's safe, you go ahead and use the `$Updatedby` item to do your calculation. 
By the way, using our (Ytria) scanEZ product you'll be able to gather these values for all docs in your database without any coding. Few simple formulas, and you've got a full report ready to export to DXL or CSV.